# Set with select clause fail

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table 1 that contains many entities and another one (table 2) that has 2 columns : the primary key of table 1 and a second column. An entity in table 1 has several other entities (from table 1 too) assigned by the second column in table 2 
example:

```
 id | type | ownerId
1 | bigObject | 1
2 | littleObj | 3
3 | littleObj | 3

id | key
1 | 2
1 | 3
```

and I want to update the ownerId of all littleObjects to the ownerId of the big objects.

What I tried:

```
UPDATE entity
SET ownerid = (SELECT ownerid
                 FROM entity
                 WHERE id = 1)
WHERE id IN (SELECT key
                FROM table_b
                WHERE id = 1)
;
```

But it says You can’t specify target table ‚entity‘ for update in FROM clause

Comment: as I can see you are: updating ownerid in entity with the value that currently is in entity where id = 1 (meaning ownerid = 1) and the condition is that the id should be in keys (2 or 3)... for me it does not make sense... please elaborate what you want to do

Comment: Ares Draguna that is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using MySQL, because that generates the error.  Use this form instead:

```
UPDATE entity e CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT ownerid
        FROM entity
        WHERE id = 1
       ) e1
    SET e.ownerid = e1.ownerid
WHERE id IN (SELECT key
             FROM table_b
             WHERE id = 1)
```

Comment: This worked exactly like I wanted it. Thank you! Didn't know about cross join yet